# how to get Gtkwindow instead of GdkWindow

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I want to get gdkwindow, I know there are method listing all gdk window opened in the desktop, But how to Get a GtkWindow?
I know GtkWindow has a property gdkwindow, but How to Get GtkWindow by GdkWindow?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish and what if any additional data/widgets are available to you?

Comment: @cpburnz   how to get gtkwindow instance by a gdkwindow xid?

Answer (score 2):

Without more context I can't really answer your question any better, but try using [`gtk.window_list_toplevels()`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwindow.html#function-gtk--window-list-toplevels). It will return the list of all top-level GTK windows for the current process.

Here's how you would devise a method to return the corresponding top-level
GTK window from a GDK window XID.

```py
def find_gtk_window(xid):
    for gtk_window in gtk.window_list_toplevels():
        if gtk_window.window.xid == xid:
            return gtk_window
```

But, if you want to list all GTK windows of other processes, then that's not (easily) possible. An answer to [How do I get a list of all windows on my gnome2 desktop using pygtk?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9376793/369450) describes the situtation pretty well.

Comment: I have a question. When I running a window1, then i open a filedialog.
why can't I directly close window1 other than close filedialog first.
but sometime in other app, the older window can be closed first. what's the reason, for example GtkFileChooserButton and GtkFileChooserDialog.

Comment: GtkFileChooserButton(can close old window first) and GtkFileChooserDialog(cannot and should close dialog first).
code there [https://github.com/majorsilence/pygtknotebook/tree/master/examples/more-pygtk](https://github.com/majorsilence/pygtknotebook/tree/master/examples/more-pygtk)

Comment: @user3085513 That should really be posted as a separate question, but that has to due with [`GTK_DIALOG_MODAL`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialogFlags). If you want to be able to go back to the parent window without closing the dialog, make sure to unset the `GTK_DIALOG_MODAL` flag which can be done with [`gtk_window_set_model()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-modal).

Comment: @user3085513 Did this post answer your original question?

Comment: I Know we can get gdkwindow from GtkWindow using gtk.Window.get_window(), Is It possible to Get GtkWindow by a Gdkwindow I already have?  Do you know GtkParasite , a tool inspecting gtkwigdets,

Comment: As the answer says, you can't get GtkWindows from other processes. GtkParasite works because it is a module that is dynamically loaded into the process that you are inspecting, so it uses `gtk_window_list_toplevels()` to get the current process's windows.